# SKTexture nearest filtering mode doesn't work (Making Pixel Art)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, antialiasing, skspritenode, sktexture

I used a relatively small image (44pixel tall) and scaled it up to have a pixel art look. I tried to change the filtering mode to nearest so the anti-aliasing would disappear but it didn't. It appears with blurry edges. I tried the same with a background getting the same result.

```
let myNode = SKSpriteNode()

class GameScene: SKScene {


    func makeNode() {

        myNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
        myNode.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        myNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image")
        myNode.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest

        return self.addChild(myNode)
    }
}
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    makeNode()

}
```

Comment: The filter mode is tricky with Sprite Kit as there are some bugs. Firstly, are you using an Atlas at all. Also what happens if you set the filtering mode on the texture before assigning it to the node.

Comment: I haven't tried using atlas here, should I?

The second suggestion seemed really promising but as I saw it, it didn't work. I guess you meant this:

    `...`
    `let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image")`
    `texture.filteringMode = .Nearest`
    
    `myNode.texture = texture`
    `...`

And thank you very much for your response! I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then. I know people have got it to work before. Are you running on device? And what version?

Comment: I'm on either late 2014 retina MacBook Pro, or iPhone 5S. But I guess I'll scale the image up in Photoshop keeping the pixelated look, and then use it in the app. I thought it would improve performance if I used small images and scaling them up with code.

Comment: Yea it sucks that it's not working. You can try Xcode 7/iOS 9 if you want and see if they fixed it. These are powerful devices, you should be fine using larger textures. It's really expensive computation and number of draw calls you need to worry about anyway. And to some extent the depth of the node tree.

Comment: I am using the latest betas of these OSes. Thank you very much for your help! You're right. With this big of a performance it doesn't matter how big images I'm using if the question is between 40 and 300 and not 300 and 4000 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** 
SKTexture nearest filtering mode is now working in Xcode 7 GM. No need to manually scale images as I've suggested below.

---

I am experiencing this same problem in Xcode 7 beta 5 with beta iOS 9 ; the *Nearest* filtering mode is seemingly ignored. In my project, scaling with nearest-neighbor scaling was previously working in Xcode 6 on iOS 8.

In the event that the bug is not resolved before the final release of iOS 9 I am pre-scaling images before I place them in their respective atlases.

To do this I wrote a simple python script to recursively find png files and scale them using [imagmagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

If you don’t have imagemagick installed, you can install it using [macports](https://www.macports.org/) like so:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

If you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) it looks like this:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

I just place this script (below) in a file called imgscaler.py within the directory above my atlas files (which I want to scale by 400% in my case) and kick it off from the terminal:

```
python imgscaler.py
```

The script looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import fnmatch


def main():
    execution_folder_name = os.getcwd()
    file_extension_name = "png"

    #
    # Collect names of files that will be manipulated
    matches = []
    for root, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(execution_folder_name):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(fileNames, '*.' + file_extension_name):
            full_name = os.path.join(root, filename)
            matches.append(full_name)

    scale_percentage = "400"

    if not __query_yes_no("This script will scale images by " + scale_percentage + "% recursively from directory " + execution_folder_name + ".  Proceed?"):
        return

    #
    # Scale the images
    for match in matches:
        execution_str = "convert " + match + " -interpolate Nearest -filter point -resize " + scale_percentage + "% " + match + "\n"
        sys.stdout.write(execution_str)
        __run_command(execution_str)


def __run_command(input_cmd):
    """Runs a command on the terminal, and returns the output in a string array.
    """
    process = subprocess.Popen(input_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    output = []
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if line != '':
            output.append(line)
        else:
            break

    return output


def __query_yes_no(question, default="yes"):
    """Asks a yes or no question, returns a true is answered "yes".
    """
    valid = {"yes": True, "y": True, "ye": True,
             "no": False, "n": False}
    if default is None:
        prompt = " [y/n] "
    elif default == "yes":
        prompt = " [Y/n] "
    elif default == "no":
        prompt = " [y/N] "
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid default answer: '%s'" % default)

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(question + prompt)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        choice = raw_input().lower()
        if default is not None and choice == '':
            sys.stdout.write(default)
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            return valid[default]
        elif choice in valid:
            sys.stdout.write(choice)
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' (or 'y' or 'n').\n")
            sys.stdout.flush()


main()
```

Change `scale_percentage` to whatever percentage you want to scale by.

BTW, I am guessing this scaling issue will eventually get resolved. I’m currently updating my code with this assumption in mind.  **This is just a bandaid** in the event the fix to nearest-neighbor scaling in SpriteKit arrives later than iOS 9.0.

Comment: Wow! What a nice solution! I was working on this iOS project as studying and having fun with it. I have a lot of other projects to work on, so I'm sorry to say that I won't have time implementing this beautiful piece to the app I was working on. Especially that I think this bug will be fixed around the next Apple event (9 September). But thank you very much! I'm sure it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Xcode7 beta / iOS9. It works if you use Xcode 6.