# How do I set the filtering mode when using setTexture in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode that changes its texture, but by default the linear filtering is enabled. I can't figure out how to make it so that it sets to nearest. I hope someone knows something about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKTexture nearest filtering mode doesn't work (Making Pixel Art)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363494/sktexture-nearest-filtering-mode-doesnt-work-making-pixel-art). The answer now works without any problems, as the accepted answer mentions.

Comment: No, the method of setting filtering mode works when you don't change the textures. But when you do, it resets to linear anyway. And that is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Filtering mode is a property of the texture, not the sprite.  So if you change the texture of a sprite, you need to also set the filtering mode of that texture if you want the sprite to continue using nearest neighbor filtering.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.